# Multiple ReduxFramework Plugin Error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, redux-framework

1- I have created new theme using ReduxFramework .
I can use option panel to change everything on my theme .

2- I have created new plugin using ReduxFramework .
I can use option panel to change everything on my plugin .

The problem is :

If I activate the plugin on my website .
Option panel of my theme Disappear and Option Panel Of plugin Show

If I disable The plugin

Option panel of my theme Show again

how can i fix it ?

Comment: You should have change for each instance of your ReduxFramework global variable separate.

Answer (score 0):

May be you declare same redux global variable in your theme and plugin, Make sure that you have different $opt_name.

```
// This is your option name where all the Redux data is stored.
$opt_name = 'custom-options-name';
```

Answer (score 0):

I applied this fix : https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework/issues/1175

The problem is solved.

But now there are a few css/style problem. Because all of them use same style/css.